# Handling location updates in background for widget refresh

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, widgetkit

I'am developing an iOS widget for my weather app, where the user can set the widget to "My location". This means the widget needs to be refreshed on location changes. Since a widget can't run a location manager in the background, apple tech support wrote that you have to setup a location manager in the main app and share the updated location data over App groups to the widget. This part works fine. I also managed to setup a location manager running in the background, but it uses too much battery and shows always the location indicator on top (blue bar) if the app is running, but I don't need this since its not a navigation app or something similar. How to configure a lightweight location manager running in the background?

```
class WidgetLocationManager: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    static let shared: WidgetLocationManager = WidgetLocationManager()
    
    let manager = CLLocationManager()
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer
        manager.distanceFilter = 1000
        manager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        manager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
        manager.activityType = .other
        manager.showsBackgroundLocationIndicator = false
    }
    
    func setupWidgetLocationManager() {
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        manager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
    }
    
    func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
        if manager.authorizationStatus == .notDetermined || manager.authorizationStatus == .denied || manager.authorizationStatus == .restricted {
            manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            manager.stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
        }
        
        if manager.authorizationStatus == .authorizedAlways || manager.authorizationStatus == .authorizedWhenInUse {
            manager.startUpdatingLocation()
            manager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
        }
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        
        if let newestLocation = locations.last {
            UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.xxx")?.set(Double(newestLocation.coordinate.latitude), forKey: "newest_location_latitude")
            UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.xxx")?.set(Double(newestLocation.coordinate.longitude), forKey: "newest_location_longitude")
            UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.xxx")?.set(Double(newestLocation.altitude), forKey: "newest_location_altitude")
            
            WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()
        }
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        
    }
}
```

Capability for background modes location is set, also mandatory strings in info.plist for location privacy info.

Comment: You should use significant location change service only. You don't need to call `startUpdatingLocation`. If you have "always" permission then the icon doesn't show blue

Comment: @Paulw11 If I remove the `startUpdatingLocation` calls, the delegate `func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])` is no longer called. Any idea why? The app has set permissions to "always"

Comment: If you are only using significant location change monitoring you should get one update almost immediately but then you will need to move about 500m before you will get a location update. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423531-startmonitoringsignificantlocati

Comment: @Paulw11 I get one update immediately but with old coordinates. I activated freeway drive in the simulator but no new location update is appearing.
I've also added as mentioned in the apple docs my `setupWidgetLocationManager` call to the `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` delegate.

Comment: Widgets aren’t appropriate for something like a freeway drive. They are a lot slower and you can at the maximum update them every 15 minutes or so. Love Activities are meant for something more detailed and immediate.

Comment: I don't believe that freeway drive will trigger significant location change either. You need to test on a real device I think.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for your help. I didn't knew that significant location change is not called in the simulator. I've tested it on a real device and it works now.